# Why does Visual Studio remove watch for new .razor files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Visual Studio Professional 2019 and now in 2022, in my Blazor client's .csproj file, I have a line inside an ItemGroup:

```
<Watch Include="**\*.razor;**\appsettings.*" />
```

That way, whenever I change a .razor file, `dotnet watch run` will rebuild and restart the web server automatically.  Great.

But now, whenever I create a .razor file in the project (such as Foo.razor), Visual Studio quite unhelpfully adds a "remove" line, such as:

```
<Watch Remove="Components\Widgets\Foo.razor" />
```

It also adds this, sometimes:

```
<Content Remove="Components\Widgets\Foo.razor" />
```

I then have to manually edit the csproj file to remove these lines.  Why is it doing this, and how can I turn it off?  Or is there something bigger that is wrong here?  Some searching found no one else dealing with this; maybe I have something wrong with my setup?

(I saw exactly the same behavior in earlier versions.)  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:  [This issue seems relevant, but it was closed without fixing anything](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27718).  Anyone have any ideas how to make it stop?

Comment: I have the same issue, it is incredible annoying, I now have the csproj file open in notepad++. Whenever something seems fishy, I press 'save all' in VS and removes strange stuff like <Content Remove=...>. It seems to come at arbitrary times while saving .razor files...

Answer (score 1):

I have reported this issue and should be resolved at some point: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27718

Comment: Any idea why it does this in the first place? Why aren't more people struggling with this?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: Steve Sanderson submitted the issue himself in August and that got buried somehow before release. I suspect not that many people have used dotnet wathc for development (spoiler alert: it is still too slow ATM). Before I commit a csproj file I now always check if this Watch exception is inserted :-(.

Comment: Seems pretty fast to me.

Comment: Well, for a medium size project it now rebuilds and restarts the whole site which takes about 5 seconds on my machine. One change in 1 css file. Hot Reload with state preservation is on the way so that should be <1s in the near future hopefully.

Comment: Yes, that will be better.

Comment: Sadly, the issue was closed without resolution.

Comment: I still experience this to this day.